# How to print output to text file from multiple functions (python)

Tags: python

I want to save the below code output to `file.txt`. The problem is that my code includes many functions.

In other words, I want my output in a text file, I'm using python but I posted as js, #python

```css
import random


Generate_Number_CHOICE = 1
Average_Calculate_CHOICE = 2
Display_Grades_CHOICE = 3
Display_Failing_Marks_CHOICE = 4
QUIT_CHOICE = 5

def display_menu():
    print('        MENU')
    print('1) Enter Your Marks')
    print('2) Get Your Average')
    print('3) Display Your Grades')
    print('4) Display Failin Marks')
    print('5) Quit')


def generate_number():

    numbers = random.sample(range(1 ,100),30)
    print(numbers)
    return numbers





def average_calculate(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    average = total // 30
    print('------------------------------------')
    print('Your Average is:', average)
    print(" ")




def display_grades(numbers):

    for mark in(numbers):
        if mark  >= 90:
         print('------------------------------------')
         print('A+',mark)
        elif mark  >= 80:
         print('------------------------------------')
         print('B+',mark )
        elif mark  >= 70:
         print('------------------------------------')
         print('C+',mark)
        elif mark  >= 60:
         print('------------------------------------')
         print('D+',mark)
        else:
         print('------------------------------------')
         print('F',mark)

    return mark
    return courses_Name


def display_failing(numbers):
    for number in (numbers):
            if number <= 59:
             print('------------------------------------')
             print("you Fail in",number)
             print(" ")


def main():
        infile = open('philosophers.txt', 'w')

        choice = 0
        while choice != QUIT_CHOICE:

            display_menu()

            choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))

            if choice == Generate_Number_CHOICE:
                numbers = generate_number()



            elif choice == Average_Calculate_CHOICE:

                average_calculate(numbers)

            elif choice == Display_Grades_CHOICE:

                mark = display_grades(numbers)


            elif choice == Display_Failing_Marks_CHOICE:

                display_failing(numbers)

            elif choice == QUIT_CHOICE:

                print('Exiting the program...')

            else:

                print('Error: invalid selection.')

main()
```

Comment: How do you run the code? What OS are you using? Why not open the file in your program and write to it in the program?

Comment: Why did you mark the python code as javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace you print statements with `infile.write('text goes here')`, also don't forget to close your file after you're done with it using `infile.close()`. Alternately you can use a `with` statement.

```
with open('philosophers.txt', 'w') as infile:
    infile.write('text')
```

and this will close the file without explicitly calling `.close`.

You can also print to a file

```
print('text', file=infile) #python 3
print >> infile, 'text' #python 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open a file (as global variable) in the beginning of your main function and in all other functions use that file handle to write whatever you want in the file.But an even better solution is to pass that file handle to each function and use the handle to write to file. Either way, don't forget to  close the file at the end of the main function.

Comment: First in the very beginning of your main fun use the keyword `global` to declare a global variable like `global fileObject` then open file `fileObject = open('file','w')`, now the variable fileObject will be accessible through every fun in the script. Don't forget to close the file at the end of the main function `fileObject.close()` does that help?